# Python nested classes inheritance

Tags: python, class, types, factory

I have a quiestion on generating classes in Python with type() function

```
class A:
    class B:
        some_field = some_value
```

object received with A constructor call is as follows:

```
a = <__main__.A object at 0x040BF730>
    B = <class '__main__.A.B'>
        some_field = 0
```

Then I tried to make the same class with type() function

```
C = type("C", (), { 'D': type('D', (), {'some_field': int()})})
```

Object received with C constructor call contains D which is not inherited from C obviously:

```
c = <__main__.C object at 0x040BF930>
    D = <class '__main__.D'>
        some_field = 0
```

Is there a method to make the same structure as A() with factory function?

Comment: Nested classes don't inherit to begin with. `__main__.A.B` does not mean `B` inherits from `A`, it just means its fully qualified name is `A.B`!

Comment: Oh, got it. But question is still about how to make **the same** structure as A() even it's name, not inheritance property.

Comment: The first argument to `type` decides its name, so `type('C.D', ...)`.